# Convergence of an Improper Integral (Determination of values of p and q that make intergral converge)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

**Q. Determine the values of p and q for which the improper integral converges**
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^{\infty}x^p[\ln(1+x)]^q\,dx
\end{equation}

After some calculation, I found out this integral diverges when:

$p,q \leq 0$ or $p \geq 0, q \leq 0$ or $p,q \geq 0$

So we have to only consider when $p < 0, q > 0 $ .

I used integration by parts method but after that, the remaining integral has a different form. For example:
\begin{equation}
\int_2^{\infty}x^p(\ln x)^q\,dx
\end{equation}

This case is rather easy because after using integration by parts, the remaining integral also has a same form, that is:

\begin{equation}
{q\over p+1}\int_2^{\infty}x^p(\ln x)^{q-1}\,dx
\end{equation}

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: $p < -1, q > 1$

Comment: @mathworker21 - How did you determine that?

Comment: @JavaMan - Oh, now I see it! Thank you so much!!